# Devexpress aspx controls not styling after publish to different server

Tags: styles, devexpress, axd

I have a few Devexpress aspx controls on a website that look fine on our development server. When I publish the exact same files to the live server, everything works, but none of the controls have any styling.

I have checked the site, in the IE dev tools, and it seems to have a link to only 1 DXR.axd while the dev server has a link to 3. Each one is different.

Don't really know where to begin checking as everything seems identical on both servers, including web.config, see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="testConnectionString" connectionString="Server=<test>;User ID=root;Password=password;Database=test" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraScheduler.v10.2.Core, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.PivotGrid.v10.2.Core, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <httpModules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <devExpress>
    <settings rightToLeft="false"/>
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="false"/>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true"/>
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl=""/>
  </devExpress>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy the "ASPxThemes" assembly (DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.vXX.Y.dll) within the server GAC or WebSite Bin folder.

This assembly stores required DevExpress ASP.NET Themes resources.

Comment: The ASPxThemes dll is neither in the GAC nor bin folder on the dev server so how can it work?

Comment: If you apply any theme, this assembly is automatically linked:  <themes enableThemesAssembly="true"/>

Comment: But it's not in the GAC or bin folder on the dev server. I have published both in the exact same way. (Published locally then copies to the server) So both should be setup the same, and seem to be as neither have the ASPxThemes dll in the places you mention, yet one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: If you are not using a theme, check whether or not you have registered the “ASPxHttpHandlerModule” Web.config element (see the original configuration file) in the publish server.

Comment: “But it's not in the GAC or bin folder on the dev server.” It is in the GAC. You can find the corresponding DLL file at “C:\Program Files\DevExpress 2010.2\Components\Sources\DevExpress.DLL\ DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v10.2.dll”

Comment: The web.config files are identical, like the one above. And have ASPxHttpHandlerModule registered.

Comment: Please illustrate what the issue looks like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5245/discussion-between-mikhail-preyskurantov-and-anothershrubery)

Comment: Schoolboy error, DevExpress was not installed on the live server.